# Recommended 100k mile maintenance

Tags: ford, maintenance, truck, f-150

I have a **2011 Ford F-150 at 97,000 miles**. I love this truck to death, am always on top of regular maintenance in terms of oil changes etc... I've been fortunate to have very little go wrong with the truck other than a MAF sensor going out around 75,000 miles.

I am hoping to drive this truck until I can teach my kids to drive (I am still years from having children, my way of saying **I love this truck I'll be buried with this truck**).

**Are there any recommended or standard maintenance procedures that are commonly done at 100k miles to keep him running his best, or is simple routine maintenance enough?**

**Additional considerations:** I will spend whatever I need to so money isn't a concern. It's a 5.0L XLT. Also, this is a Texas truck that has never seen road salt or salt water environments. Two trips to the mountains of Colorado a year and no heavy mudding or anything like that. It's on 20in Fuel wheels with Nitto Terra Grapplers and a 2in leveling kit that were put on this past summer, alignment and everything done immediately after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link with the recommended maintenance schedule

http://www.ford-trucks.com/how-tos/a/ford-f150-basic-maintenance-schedule-359521

Here is a screenshot of the 100K maintenance recommendations

[image]

The left column is recommended maintenance, the right column is recommended inspections

Most owners manuals will also list the recommended service intervals, I would recommend checking that as well.

Comment: While the link is a good reference, it would be much better to bring the information here. Links can die and/or be changed. If you bring the data here and use the link as a reference, it's here in perpetuity whether the link goes stale or not.